# C++ - threaded tree, ordered traversal

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I've just implemented a threaded tree in C++, and now I'm trying to `cout` all the elements in order.

The tree was a binary sorted tree (not balanced) before I've threaded it.

I've tried doing this:

```
E min = _min(root); //returns the minimum element of the tree
E max = _max(root); //returns the maximum element of the tree

while (min != max)
{
  std::cout << min << ", ";
  min = _successor(root, min);
}
std::cout << max << ", ";
std::cout << std::endl;
```

but since the tree is now threaded, my successor function always returns the minimum of the whole tree (basically, it goes once in the right subtree, and then goes in the left subtree as many times as possible, until it finds a leaf.) So when I try to call this function, it only `cout` 1's (because 1 is the minimum value of my tree).

Also, I've tried something else:

```
  E min = _min(root); //returns min element of the tree
  E max = _max(root); //returns max element of the tree
  Node* tmp = _getNode(root, min); //returns the node of the specified element, therefore the minimum node of the tree
  while(tmp->data < max)
  {
           std::cout << tmp->data << ", ";
           tmp = _getNode(root, tmp->data)->rightChild; //gets the right child node of tmp
  }
  std::cout << tmp->data << ", ";
```

However, by doing this, there are values that are ignored. (See image below)
[image]

(Green links have been added after the threading of the tree.)
If you see, for example, the node #6 never gets visited from the very last algorithm, because it's not the right child of any node in the tree...

Here's the output of the previous function:

```
1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 11, 71
```

Does anyone have an idea of how I could fix this, or any tips for my problem?

Thanks

EDIT: After all I just had to traverse the tree from the minimum to the maximum AND modify my _predecessor and _successor methods, so they wouldn't check in subtrees that are threaded. :)

Hope it helps future readers.

Comment: I don't think your picture is totally correct.  I think the left link from 8 should be a thread back to 7.  Similarly, 9 should have a left thread to 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Node* n = _min(root);
while (n->right) {
    cout << n->val << ", ";
    n = _successor(n);
}
cout << n->val << endl;
```

This is basically your first code (note that I assume that the tree is non-empty as do you). This also won't give you a trailing ','.

The important thing is to get your successor function correct. It should be like this

```
Node* _successor(Node* n) {
    if (is_thread(o, RIGHT)) return o->right;
    return _min(o->right);
}
```

And for completeness

```
Node* _min(Node* n) {
    while (!is_thread(o, LEFT)) n = o->left;
    return n;
}
```

For both of these all the green arrows are threads.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen threaded trees before, but I'll take a stab at this anyway.  To build an inorder traversal, you could approach the root of the tree from two directions at once:

1. Start at the root.
2. Follow all left links until you find one that points to null.  That element is the tree's minimum value.
3. Follow all right links until you reach the root.  If you've built the tree correctly, this should traverse every element in increasing order.
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 in the opposite direction (find the max element, walk backwards).
5. Join these two lists with the root in the middle.

That's probably not the fastest algorithm but I think it'll produce a correct answer.  And you didn't have to use recursion, which I guess is the whole point for using a threaded tree.

Comment: Would this work if the 21 in the picture above had a right child (ie 23)? During step 2 and 3 you would miss the 'C' in this tree: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7a/Threaded_tree.svg

Comment: @Kristo Nice try though, It gave the wanted result for this tree though :P Thanks!

Comment: @Moberg, you're right.  D'oh.  My attempt at this also wouldn't handle a 4 and 3.5 inserted to the right of 3 in the OP's diagram (it would miss the 3.5).

Comment: @Pacane, be careful with that.  Your teacher might use a *different* tree to grade your work.

Comment: @Kristo Oh I know, this doesn't work, I was just saying it was a good attempt... I thanked you for trying at least :-P

Comment: @Pacane, I would remove your upvote then (I assume it was you).  This is *not* a correct solution.  I hope I at least gave you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

After all I just had to traverse the tree from the minimum to the maximum
AND
modify my _predecessor and _successor methods, so they wouldn't check in subtrees that are threaded. :)

Hope it helps future readers.